# How do I retrieve a cookie sent by the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, server

I expect the browser to send a cookie with a given name. How do I read this cookie?

I'm trying to read the docs: [Example: Set and Retrieve Cookies in a Message Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies#example-set-and-retrieve-cookies-in-a-message-handler), [`HttpRequestHeadersExtensions.GetCookies` Method `(HttpRequestHeaders, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995249(v=vs.118)#httprequestheadersextensionsgetcookies-method-httprequestheadersstring), [`CookieHeaderValue` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944846(v=vs.108))

But unfortunately these docs make little sense to me :(

First: They provided such an example of a code that retrieves a cookie (edited for brevity):

```cs
var cookie = request.Headers.GetCookies(SessionIdToken).FirstOrDefault();
sessionId = cookie[SessionIdToken].Value;
```

But `GetCookies` returns a `Collection<CookieHeaderValue>`, meaning that `cookie` in the above example should be of type `CookieHeaderValue`, which as per the docs I linked to does not have the `[]` property, so what does `cookie[SessionIdToken]` mean?

Then: What does `GetCookies` actually do?

As per the docs:

> Gets any cookie headers present in the request that contain a cookie state whose name that matches the specified value.

I don't understand this description :(

Why does it *get any cookie headers that contain a cookie state*? What is a *cookie state*? In my mental model a cookie is a small piece of data that has a name and meta parameters such as expiration date.

Why does it get cookie headers present in the request that contain a cookie state *whose name matches the specified value*? What does the word *matches* here mean and how is it different from *whose name **is equal to** the specified value*? The word *matches* brings regular expressions to my mind but it does not seem that regexps is what this method accepts.

All I want is to retrieve the value of a cookie by its name. Is it possible? And how?

Note that I'm still stuck with .Net Framework rather than .Net Core, although this is supposed to be changed soon.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Looks like you're looking at Web API Message Handlers, but it seems you want something more straightforward, like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/annathurai/cookies-in-Asp-Net/) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178194(v=vs.100)).

Comment: @wazz Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I'm trying to write an authentication filter ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters ) and sadly,  I don't have a `System.Web.HttpRequest` object but only a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` (as a property of `System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpAuthenticationContext`), which doesn't seem to have a `Cookies` property :(

Answer (score 0):

Found your post while wondering the same thing.
The docs you link are a bit confusing, but from the code sample I figured out how you retrieve the value

```
var cookie= request.Headers.GetCookies("your-cookie-name").FirstOrDefault(); // in case there are more than one - this returns an Enumerable, we know there should only be one
if(cookie!= null)// the cookie we are looking for exists
{
    var cookieValue = cookie["your-cookie-name"].Value;
}
```

I suspect the *matches* is a refereence to the ability to hold multiple values with the same name.